# Proving global exponential stability of a perturbed system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system

$$\dot{x} = \left(A + \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}BB^TP\right)x + Dg(t,y),\quad y=Cx,$$

where $g(t,y)$ is continuously differentiable and satisfies

$$\Vert g(t,y)\Vert_2 \le k\Vert y\Vert_2,\, \forall t\ge0,\, \forall \Vert y\Vert_y\le r,$$

for some $r>0$. Given the equation ($P,Q$ symmetric positive definite, $\varepsilon>0$, $0<\gamma<1/k$.)

$$PA + A^TP+\varepsilon Q -\frac1\varepsilon PBB^TP+\frac1\gamma PDD^TP + \frac1\gamma C^TC=0.$$

Using $V(x)=x^TPx$ it can be shown that for

$$\dot{V} \le -\varepsilon x^TQx.$$

---

I have worked through the above in an exam question but the last part says using this information determine whether the system is *globally exponentially stable*.

Now the Lyapunov condition for exponential stability is

- $V$ is positive definite.
- $\dot{V}$ is negative definite.
- $V(x)$ is radially unbounded.
- $\dot{V}\le -\varepsilon V(x)$.

So the first three conditions are satisfied however i'm not so sure the final condition is satisfied since we have $\dot{V} \le -\varepsilon x^TQx \not= -\varepsilon x^TPx = -\varepsilon V(x)$. So this can't be exponentially stable unless we know $x^TQx\ge x^TPx$. Is there any way to deduce this from the information given?

Comment: $\dot{V}\leq -\epsilon x^TQx\leq-\epsilon\frac{\lambda_{min}(Q)}{\lambda_{\max}(P)}V$ where $\lambda_{min}(Q)$ denotes the minimum eigenvalue of $Q$ and $\lambda_{\max}(P)$ the maximum eigenvalue of $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $P$ and $Q$ are both positive definite, for $V(x) = x^TPx$ we have

$$\lambda_{min}(Q)\Vert x\Vert^2\le x^TQx\le \lambda_{max}(Q)\Vert x\Vert^2\tag{1}$$

$$\lambda_{min}(P)\Vert x\Vert^2\le V(x)\le \lambda_{max}(P)\Vert x\Vert^2\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$:

$$-x^TQx\le-\lambda_{min}(Q)\Vert x\Vert^2$$

and from $(2)$:

$$\frac1{\lambda_{max}(P)}V(x)\le \Vert x\Vert^2$$

This yields

$$\dot{V}(x) \le -\varepsilon x^TQx\le-\varepsilon \frac{\lambda_{min}(Q)}{\lambda_{max}(P)}V(x)$$

Hence the origin of this system is globally exponentially stable.